# A Simple Logging Filter for Play

Tags: java, filter, playframework

In [the official document,](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters) I saw this logging filter.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage; import java.util.function.Function; import javax.inject.Inject; import akka.stream.Materializer; import play.Logger; import play.mvc.*;

public class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

    @Inject
    public LoggingFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
            Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
            Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long requestTime = endTime - startTime;

            Logger.info("{} {} took {}ms and returned {}",
                requestHeader.method(), requestHeader.uri(), requestTime, result.status());

            return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + requestTime);
        });
    } }
```

Although this is a basic question, don't we need to configure any setting for this filter?   After creating this filter class in PlayApplication, this filter will be applicable to all requests?

Second, they explain that `nextFilter` is the next action.  However, there seems to be no setting for it here. So, in this case, what action will be executed?

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create in the root package a `Filters` class extending the `DefaultHttpFilters` and pass your filter to the varargs constructor. Play will automatically look into this `Filters` class in order to find the filters you have created. Your filter will be available to all requests.

```
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {
  @Inject
  public Filters(LoggingFilter logging) {
    super(logging);
  }
}
```

You can define and apply several filters:

```
public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {
  @Inject
  public Filters(GzipFilter gzip, LoggingFilter logging) {
    super(gzip, logging);
  }
}
```

In this case, the `nextFilter` parameter represents the next action in the filter chain.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question dates a bit but you can also register the filter in configuration if you do not want to add a class in the root package

```
play.filters.enabled += "com.company.application.util.http.LoggingFilter"
```

Syntax is for play 2.8 it might differ on previous versions